# TzStats: delegators list

Tags: api, tzstats

After tzscan shutdown, I am trying to use tzstats as an alternative to calculate delegating rewards. 
Is there a way to get a list of delegators for a specific baking address and cycle using the tzstats api?

Comment: you should ask only questions that relevant to one topic, there are two very different questions here which you should separate into two individual questions.

Comment: Before this question gets closed, please follow Franks advice to get a good answer and edit this question to ask only how to get the delegators and create another question to ask about income precision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://api.tzstats.com/tables/account?delegate=tz1ADDRESS

The full API used for the 'Delegators' tab:

```
curl 'https://api.tzstats.com/tables/account?delegate=tz1ADDRESS&is_funded=1&columns=row_id,address,delegated_balance,spendable_balance,unclaimed_balance,delegated_since_time,delegated_since&limit=60'
```

Comment: posting a link and suggesting to go elsewhere is not an answer, if you have an answer please provide it

Comment: adjusted answer. discovered by using Chrome's dev tools under 'Network' tab.